# What can I buy with cryptocurrencies today

Tags: payment, payment-processors

I have read about [CoinPayments](https://www.coinpayments.net/store-directory), which allow stores to sell goods for crypto currencies. Are there more services like them ? Where else can I expect crypto coins to be accepted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Lilia Etkina in Long Island City can fix your teeth or do a cleaning for a fraction of a Bitcoin.

https://www.zocdoc.com/dentist/liliya-etkina-dds-58296